# rewinding a Java BufferedReader to the beginning of a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

File objects in python have a method called `seek` that allows you to place the file bookmark anywhere in the file.  In particular `seek(0)` puts the file bookmark back at the beginning of a file.

Can a similar thing be done to a BufferedReader in Java, or do you just have to make a new one?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that on a `BufferedReader` because he can only return a specified amount of bytes (in fact his buffer size).
What you can do:

```
FileInputStream fileinputStream = ...;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileinputStream));


// reset to the beginning of file and overwrite old buffered reader
fileinputStream.getChannel().position(0);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileinputStream));
```

Here is some doc about the `FileChannel` I used with `fileinputStream.getChannel():`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html

So to your question: Yes, you need to create a new one

Comment: In Java you can also `seek` on a `RandomAccessFile` object. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. All you can do is to make a new one. Mark/reset only works if the file is smaller than the buffer size.  This is, of course, unacceptable.